# ftp file transfer using socket programming python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sockets

When i execute the code the file is sent successfully; i also tried to use tcpdump to check whether the file is actually transferring o not and it was but i can't find the file in destination vsftpd server(in kali linux)

```
#!/bin/python3
import ftplib
import socket
import os
def main():
        file_path=input("enter the absolute_file_path of the file you want to upload",)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('192.168.190.130',21))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        s.send('USER harsh'.encode('utf-8')+'\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        s.send('PASS iacsd@123'.encode('utf-8')+'\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
        s.send(f"{file_path}{filesize}\r\n".encode('utf-8'))

        # Open the file in binary mode and send its content
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                while True:
                        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        if not bytes_read:
                                break
                        s.sendall(bytes_read)
                print("File uploaded successfully.")
#       s.send(f"{file_path}{filesize}".encode('utf-8'))
#       with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
#               bytes_read = f.read()
#               s.sendall(bytes_read)
#       file=open(file_path,'r')
#       data = file.read()
#       s.send(str(data).encode('utf-8'))
#       os.system('put file')
if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

This is the python script i wrote in debian and in kali linux vsftpd is running with 21 port open/connected to debian machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are implementing is not actually the "real" FTP protocol, but some custom protocol which *resembles* FTP for the first few commands (ie, logging in) but then totally diverges from "real" FTP for actually transferring data. Data transfers in FTP are done with a separate TCP connection, where the parameters and direction of this connection are exchanged using `PORT` and `PASV` commands (or `EPRT` and `EPSV` for IPv6), and then commands like `STOR` and `RETR` are used to perform the actual transfers.

I recommend that you use [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html), which actually implements the real FTP protocol. If you really want to implement it by your own, please study the actual standard -  [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959)